# How do you add a link in a swf file?

Tags: html, css, actionscript-3, flash

I am using HTML and I want to embed it and link it to my other webpages. It is in offline mode and I've been searching a lot and found this:

```
MyClickTagButton.addEventListener(
  MouseEvent.CLICK,
  function():void {
    if (root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:" || root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG.substr(0,6) == "https:") {
      navigateToURL(
        new URLRequest(root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG), "_blank"
      );
    }``
  }
);
```

But what I don't understand is how to put my link. Because my website links are only "person.html", "welcome.html", etc. If you know how, please help me. I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think you need that 'CSS' tag. I think you need this tagged with 'ActionScript'.

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to wrap the embed object in anchor tags?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open it in Adobe Flash builder (or other swf (Shock Wave Flash) editors) and add the Actionscript 3 to create an event handler for the movie clip and add the URL:

```html
<pre>
ACTIONSCRIPT 3 CODE:

var mySWF:String = "Your SWF movie clip name here";
mySWF.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToUrl);
function goToUrl:void {
   var url:String = "Your URL here";
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
   try {
      navigateToURL(request, '_blank');
   } catch (e:Error) {
     trace("Error occurred!");
   }
}

</pre>
```